# filter _.any() function doesn't work underscore.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, underscore.js, any

I have a problem with collection functions filter_.any() from underscore.js. 
the part of code with filter() will never execute. I can't understand why?
I took this code from this example http://blog.pixelingene.com/demos/d3_tree_clipPath/  and I included the same underscore-min.js library into my project but it didn't help to resolve my problem

can someone please help me how to resolve this issue? or may be some alternative way ? Thanks

```
function setupMouseEvents()
{           
    ui.nodeGroup.on('mouseover', function (d, i)
    {
        d3.select(this).select("rect").classed("hover", true);
    })
            .on('mouseout', function (d, i)
            {  
                d3.select(this).select("rect").classed("hover", false);
            })
            .on('click', function (nd, i)
            {
                // Walk parent chain
                var ancestors = [];
                var parent = nd;
                while (!_.isUndefined(parent)) {
                    ancestors.push(parent);
                    parent = parent.parent;
                }
                // Get the matched links
                var matchedLinks = [];
                console.log(ancestors);   
                ui.linkGroup.selectAll('path.link')
                        .filter(function (d, i)
                        {               
                            return _.any(ancestors, function (p)
                            {
                                return p === d.target;
                            });
                        })
                        .each(function (d)
                        {
                            matchedLinks.push(d);
                        });
                        console.log(matchedLinks);
                animateParentChain(matchedLinks);
            });
}
```

Comment: If it's never executed maybe `ui.linkGroup.selectAll('path.link')` is an empty collection? Log its `.length` to find out.

Comment: no, I just checked it and it's not empty.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(ancestors)` **inside** the `.filter function`, and to `console.log(p, d.target)` inside the `any` function body?

Comment: yes, I tried. it doesn't matter what I'm trying to output to console the `.filter function` will never execute. so the program doesn't go inside filter function. and that's why my result array `matchedLinks` always empty

Comment: Just in case I would say that in my NetBeans project in this function I have two warning messages for variables `_.any` and `_.isUndefined` and it said that **The global variable "_" is not declared**. I'm not sure if this is the reason of my problem but anyway just would like to let you know about it

Comment: now I declared it `/* global _ */` but it doesn't solve the problem with `filter function`. First of all I need to go inside of this function and then probably I  will find some errors

Comment: @metron you may want to add information if you want some help: what is your html structure, dataset, and how is the cart generated. Please create a jsfiddle or a code snippet in the question.

Comment: unfortunately I can't create jsfiddle which will be work. Sorry! I tried to attach external libraries but all of them not found. Here is what I did https://jsfiddle.net/H3W3k/55/